# Search twitter by language

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

In twitter by using lang operator you can search for retrieving tweets from a particular language: For example, the following search will return tweets only in english:

```
https://twitter.com/search?q=lang:en
```

Is there a way to achieve this using twitter api, especially using twitter4j. I know there is a language attribute for search but it also requires at least one keyword to make a search, I would like to search by a particular language without giving any keyword query. The following command in java driver returns the following error:

```
Query searchQuery = new Query() //
                        .count(resultsPerPage) //
                        .since(since)//
                        .lang("en");

400:The request was invalid. An accompanying error message will explain why. This is the status code will be returned during version 1.0 rate limiting(https://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate-limiting). In API v1.1, a request without authentication is considered invalid and you will get this response.
message - Query parameters are missing
code - 25
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass the same do you use in the twitter search, your query will be like:

```
new Query("lang:en")
```

Comment: How would i search a paticular hastag and langugae based in single query

Comment: @muthu Is the same, new Query("lang:en #twitter")

Comment: IF I use this, I get the tweets containing english and other languages. What if I want only english language tweets?

Comment: @NithishInpursuitOfhappiness sorry i got a mistake, new Query("lang:en AND #twitter")

Comment: Language filter works better once i switched to jtwitter instead of twitter4j...the keyword search is also more efficient over there

Comment: can we use the query for streaming tweets?

Comment: Yes, you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Using twitter4j,

`Query query = new Query();
 query.setLang("en");
 query.setQuery(searchQuery);`