# Twitter4j: Query on Different Languages

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am working on a project on Java with Twitter4j. My goal is to fetch tweets from different languages on specific keywords. As answered in [Search twitter by language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627437/search-twitter-by-language) you can easily fetch tweets in **one** language based on specific keywords. My problem though is a bit different: I have different languages and I want to query different keywords on each one of them. Here is part of my code so far:

```
FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery(); 
String[] lang = {"el"};                         // for the Greek language
String[] keywords={"ο, η, το, του, τον, οι"};  // some common keywords
fq.language(lang);
fq.track(keywords);
twitterStream.addListener(listener);
twitterStream.filter(fq);
```

This works all fine. Now I would like to add another search to work in "parallel", something like:

```
String[] lang2={"el, en"};
String[] keywords2={"ο, η, το, του, τον, οι, the, a, and, it"};
```

The problem is that I would like to get tweets in Greek containing only the Greek common words (and not the English ones) and vice versa (that is, I wouldn't like to search for the keyword "it" in Greek, but only in English). Any solution -if possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why dont you think to run two different applications for each language?

Comment: Thanks Mehmet for the reply. Well, actually I would like to run this for 6 different languages on a one-month period in (almost) real-time. So, if I try to do something like this, I guess that I will have to create 6 different accounts and probably need some PCs to run it in parallel...

Comment: Actually, you really need to have 6 different accounts but you don't have to have 6 different PCs because you can run all streaming apps on one machine. I was running 9 different streaming apps on one linux server. It works.

Comment: Huh, I see. So, I guess that I will have to go multi-thread (or do you mean simply 6 different Java programmes?). You may answer -instead of comment- so that I mark the question as solved. Thanks a lot Mehmet.

Comment: How did that worked out for you?